# ViewChild and focus()

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-template

I have a component which contains a textarea which is hidden by default :

```
<div class="action ui-g-2" (click)="toggleEditable()">edit</div>
<textarea [hidden]="!whyModel.inEdition" #myname id="textBox_{{whyModel.id}}" pInputTextarea focus="true" [(ngModel)]="whyModel.description"></textarea>
```

When I click on the "edit" div I want to show the textarea and put focus on it :

```
@ViewChild('myname') input: ElementRef;
...
private toggleEditable(): void {
  this.whyModel.toggleEditable();
  this.input.nativeElement.focus();
}
```

The "show" part  is working but not the focus part. What do I miss?

Answer (score 17):

Bindings are only updated when change detection runs, which is usually after an event handler completed. This is to late for your use case, because the event handler itself depends already on the effect of change detection.

You can enforce change detection immediately (synchronically) by calling `detectChanges()`

```ts
constructor(private cdRef:ChangeDetectorRef) {}

@ViewChild('myname') input: ElementRef;
...
private toggleEditable(): void {
  this.whyModel.toggleEditable();
  this.cdRef.detectChanges();
  this.input.nativeElement.focus();
}
```

Comment: Ok this is working but I'm not sure to understand. When you say "binding" you talk about the viewChild? I used the hidden functionnality because I thought that viewChild can be binded only to existing DOM element, even on hidden ones, this is not the case? What you say is that the viewChild will be available only after that my element is no more hidden?

Comment: I assumed that `[hidden]="!whyModel.inEdition"` is depending on the effect of `this.whyModel.toggleEditable();` and that focusing a hidden element won't work (not checked and don't remember if that's true, therefore did some guesswork ;-) )

Answer (score 3):

You can also 'force' the focus with AfterViewCheck. I simplified your code for the demo purposes:

**Typescript:**

```
  editable;

  @ViewChild('myname') input: ElementRef;
  private toggleEditable(): void {
      this.editable = !this.editable;
   }

   ngAfterViewChecked(){
     if(this.editable){
          this.input.nativeElement.focus();
     }
   }
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="action ui-g-2" (click)="toggleEditable()">edit</div>
<br>
<textarea [hidden]="!editable" #myname id="textBox_{{id}}" pInputTextarea
   focus="true" [(ngModel)]="description"></textarea>
```

**[Stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9ytz4d?file=app%2Fapp.component.html)**

Comment: I think your solution is better than @gunter, is cleaner in the angular way.

Comment: @titusfx, that's one nice comment :) Thanks. I am glad could help!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `@ViewChild` and `focus()` to focus on a particular element.
It can be used like this:

In HTML file (abc.component.html)

```
<form #data="ngForm">
<input class="text-field" type="text" name="name" >
<input class="text-field" type="text" name="surname">
<input class="text-field" type="text" name="company">
</form>


<button type="submit" value="Submit" (click)="submitData(data.value)">Submit</button>


<input class="text-field" type="text" name="City" #setFocusField>
<input class="text-field" type="text" name="State">
```

In TypeScript file (abc.component.ts)

```
@ViewChild('setFocusField') setFocusField: any;

submitData(data:any){
  this.setFocusField.focus();
}
```

When you click on the submit button, the focus will be set to the field "City".

**Another way to achieve this:**

In above code, instead of `any` on `ViewChild` field, we can use `ElementRef`.

In that case typescript file changes will be as follow:

(abc.component.ts)

```
@ViewChild('setFocusField') setFocusField: ElementRef;

submitData(data:any){
  this.setFocusField.nativeElement.focus();
}
```